# C# ArgumentOutOfRangeException in dataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, exception

I was getting this error while programming, went through some debugging, googling processes however I could not find the problem and I ask for your help!

```
        MessageBox.Show(dataGridView1.RowCount.ToString());
        MessageBox.Show(dataGridView1.ColumnCount.ToString());
        MessageBox.Show(dataGridView1.SelectedRows[1].Cells[5].Value.ToString()); //This
```

According to my research, ArgumentOutOfRangeException is thrown when it's out of range.

From above code, rowcount was 11 and columncount was 7.

However my third line code throws the ArgumentOutOfRangeException:
[image: Error]

But again, when I put 0 instead of 1 for SelectedRows, it works fine. The rest don't work.

I feel like I'm doing everything right. Can someone please help this beginner? Thank you for reading :)

Comment: How many rows are selected ,probably you have selected only on row with index 0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is because the `SelectedRows` is different from the `Rows`. `SelectedRows` are the rows which you selected, `Rows` represent all the `Rows` you have in your `dataGridView1`.

Therefore, in your case, although your `dataGridView1` has 11 rows, if only two are selected, you could not get `SelectedRows` with index `2` for example.

If you change your code to use `Rows` instead:

```
MessageBox.Show(dataGridView1.Rows[1].Cells[5].Value.ToString()); //This
```

Then you could get the value in the `Rows` and `Cells` with the index as high as the `RowCount - 1` and `ColumnCount - 1` respectively.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I was just referencing the wrong value then. I will accept the answer when in 5 minutes when the website allows me. Thank you again :)

Answer (score 0):

Well, the index is zero based, which means that if you select ONE row, the actual selected row is at index 0. What you're trying to do in the code above is to reference the "second" row in the selection. If only one row is selected, this will fail.

```
Index     Line     Data field   
0         1       Some more data
1         2       Bouncy Castle
```

Comment: Thank you for your explanation! I just didnt have proper understanding of what SelectedRows's value is I guess. Appreciate your attention sir :)